# Eclipse, PyDev "interpreter does not exist in filesystem"

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, interpreter

I recently wanted to start programming with python and therefore set up my eclipse with PyDev. Now, i followed the step-by-step Tutorial at

> http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.htm

l but when i create my first PyDev Project i get the error:

> "The interpreter configured does not exist in the filesystem: python"

I am using Eclipse 4.3, Python 2.7 and I installed PyDev via the eclipse 'Install new software' option. I did not configure any Jython/IronPython interpreters and the following is how my python-interpreter preferences look like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Checkout the difference between picture from here http://pydev.org/images/interpreter.png and picture you post it. You dont specified full path to python executable

Comment: OH dear thats embarrasing, i used the quick-config and because the tutorial has a little older style than my eclipse but the lib-files were all there i assumed it worked. 

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an introduced bug as part of the latest changes done in PyDev interpreter (it should work even without a full path -- please create a new issue at the PyDev tracker: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ with the error you get when running).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after installing python.
Here are my findings and solution for it:

Findings: This issue occurs when pydev was not able to locate python interpreter.

Solution: Configure the python path.
Steps:

Launch Eclipse -> Click on Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> Then browse and change the python interpreter path.
Check below screen for this.

NOTE: While installing python, we get a window where we get to see the path where python would be installed. So we can copy the same path here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but when I put in the location I get when I type in "where python", it comes up with an error saying "The file cannot be accessed by the system". I'm using Windows 10 and photon eclipse 4.14